# I need a matrix in order to calculate g-inverse of it

Tags: regression, self-study, generalized-linear-model, matrix, matrix-inverse

I want to calculate g-inverse of a matrix, which has 4 rows and not a square matrix and has no inverse.  Please help me find such a sound (good) matrix. I only need a matrix. You can suggest a book or a lecture-note link..etc to find it. Then I will be able to calculate g-inverse of this matrix by myself. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by g-inverse you mean [generalized inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse), then any old matrix will do.

For example, you could use a random matrix, such as output from `rand(4,6)` in `Octave`:

```
A=
0.1948332   0.8922737   0.7884769   0.8150400   0.0424719   0.5295926
0.8334978   0.5147604   0.8705055   0.3874084   0.6006895   0.9989425
0.1646716   0.4624619   0.7210477   0.4446329   0.5968465   0.5214182
0.0044496   0.2984885   0.3540282   0.8680687   0.2511311   0.0065502
```

Or a simple one

```
B = 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
```

Comment: which program did you use to find such a random matrix?

Comment: @B11b I used [`Octave`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/), but the same code would work in MATLAB. You could also use [`R`](http://www.r-project.org/), e.g. `matrix(runif(20,0,1),4,5)`, or just generate random numbers in `Microsoft Office Excel`/`LibreOffice Calc` using `RAND()`.